# Webpack splitChunks optimization is throwing errors when i integrate its build into another project

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, webpack-splitchunks

I have a common components project and to its webpack i added chunk splitting to reduse bundle size. When i integrate this project to the other project and run it i get errors that components are undefined, why? without splitChunks optimization it works fine.

```
`splitChunks: {
   chunks: "all",
}`
```

Also my project doesn't have index.html, because its made of only components, maybe that means something.

I want it to work with spliCHunks as well, why this spliiting makes my componenets undefined

Comment: Hey, would you be able to include the exact error messages you are getting? Can you also include the commands or code that you are running which causes these errors to occur?